# One part of my CSS animation is resetting. I don't want it to

Tags: css, animation, rotation, css-animations

I am trying to animate some ice cubes dropping into a cup. The animation should fall, spin while falling, hit the bottom of the div, then slightly bounce back up then go back to the bottom of the div. Currently, everything is working except my img's rotation is reseting after the animation. The falling part of the animation is not reseting even though the fall and rotate are both part of the same animation.

```
@-webkit-keyframes ice_1 {
    45% { -webkit-transform: translateY(920px) rotate(180deg) ;} 
    50% { -webkit-transform: translateY(900px) ;} 
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(920px);} 
}


img[src="images/cube.png"] {
    -webkit-animation: ice_1 5s linear 1 forwards;
}
```

Comment: can u add a jsfiddle with some actual divs to play with?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lee45276/4mCnt/   EDIT: Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the `transform` shorthand is resetting the `rotate()` function to 0 on the second and third frame. You have to explicitly include `rotate(180deg)` for the entire animation:

```
@-webkit-keyframes ice_1 {
    45% { -webkit-transform: translateY(920px) rotate(180deg); } 
    50% { -webkit-transform: translateY(900px) rotate(180deg); } 
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(920px) rotate(180deg); } 
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for helping a newbie out. Just started HTML & CSS last month and I'm loving how helpful the community is!